# Approximating numerical solution of differential equations by another differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose there is a partial differential equation (say second order, two independent variables and nonlinear) and I have a method to solve differential equations of this form to very good accuracy numerically. For sake of simplicity, let me refer to this equation as $E$.

Now my question- Is there a way to solve other arbitrary differential equations (I'll call them required equations $R$ from now) by reposing the problem as a cascading set of $E$s?

Here is a relatively more clear version of my question-

Say I have a set of initial conditions well defined. My task is to obtain the output of $R$ with these initial conditions. I find that $R$ is painful to solve even numerically. But, I do have a magically simple way to solve $E$. So what I want to do is to build a set of $E$s, say $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$. Now I use the original initial conditions and obtain a solution using $E_1$. I use the solution of $E_1$ as the initial conditions for $E_2$, and so on. The solution of $E_3$, or in general, $E_n$ must be an approximate solution of $R$ subject to the original initial conditions.

I want to know if this is possible at all. What differential equations can be solved this way for a given structure of $E$?

A relatively more mathematical (but by no means rigorous) representation-

Given an $U(0,x)$ as my initial conditions, equation $R$ is used to obtain $U(y,x)$.

I want to solve it in the following way-

Use $U(0,x)$ as initial conditions for $E_1$ which gives $U(y_1,x)$.

$U(y_1,x)$ is used as initial conditions for $E_2$ to obtain $U(y_2,x)$.

.

.

.

$U(y_{n-1},x)$ is used as initial conditions for $E_n$ and the result is $U(y,x)$ which is the same as what would have been obtained by solving $R$ directly using $U(0,x)$ as initial conditions.

Clarification: $E_m$ is different from $E_n$ in its choice of coefficients.

Another clarification: I am assuming I have found a way to solve $E$ which has precisely zero computation cost. I understand this is probably not possible, but I find my question very intriguing even otherwise.

Comment: This is Mathematical Stack Exchange. You might try less wordy, more mathematical (hint: formulas), that would be an *absolutely* more clear vision.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, I am not sure how to put this particular question in a mathematical form (non-math major here). I'll give it a shot nevertheless.

Comment: Particular?! I'm not sure when I have seen anything nearly as vague.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant by particular. I meant I really have no idea how to represent this question mathematically.

Comment: If it can't be formulated mathematically, chances are, it doesn't belong to a site devoted to mathematics.

Comment: I think it CAN be formulated mathematically. My poor formal math skills has not equipped me with the ability to do it. I'll wait for an hour or so and see if someone can point me in the right direction. If not, I'll delete it. Thanks!